# JavaScript/HTML/CSS applications on Android devices - extremely slow

Tags: javascript, android, css, html, html5-canvas

We are making some JavaScript games. They run perfectly on iPhone and iPad and desktop as well. The biggest problem are Android devices. All tablets we have with Honeycomb OS 3.x (Samsung Tab 10.1, Motorola Xoom, Acer Iconia, etc.) are extremely slow when JavaScript is executed and content is rendered. It is better on 2.x phones, but still far behind Apple devices…

We tried to use the traditional approach with **div element** as well as **HTML5 canvas**, but even simple bouncing ball example is extremely slow (If you want to test it, access http://sie.mautilus.com/canvas).

If we disable in the debug menu on Android the *Enable OpenGL Rendering* it is slightly better, but still not usable for wide audience, not speaking about the fact, that normal user will not do this…

This makes the JavaScript based user interface, which is event bit complicated totally unusable on Android…

How it is that the simple bouncing ball, which was running in MS-DOS on my Intel 386 machine is unusable on high-end tablets with dual-core 1 GHz Cortex-A9 CPUs?

See also there:
 
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17353
 
http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/fc13b40165db8a00?pli=1a

Regards,
STeN

Comment: Really intresting , for my Galaxy Y with 833mhz a JS raycaster works just fine :/ ... really a strange isssue!

Comment: Hi,  Abhishek  -you said the "JS raycaster" - can you be more specific? Can you send a link there? Anyway the Galaxy Y is the QVGA gingerbread phone, not tablet...

Comment: But the processor for galaxy is even worse :P 

    http://darkyen.webs.com/Raycastv3.html It uses mouse events so erm kinda not for a tablet but if u see the rendering loop works quite fine. I will try to write a one with touch event later tonight

Comment: Hi - wold be great if you can modify it for touch screens and add kind of FPS text to the screen corner, so we can compare the results... I am looking for your response! Thanks.

Comment: "How it is that the simple bouncing ball, which was running in MS-DOS on my Intel 386 machine is unusable on high-end tablets with dual-core 1 GHz Cortex-A9 CPUs?" How is it that my bananas don't roll down hill as nicely as melons? They're both fruits, they should work exactly the same way.

Comment: What browser specifically were you having this problem with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that it's very slow on android devices, i ran into the same problem and searching the internet I only find people that agree with us.

I did a few things to speed things up (although it comes with lower quality). I also only checked on HTC Sensation and Samsung galaxy tab 10.1. I do think that you will need to use different settings for different phones.

1. set the screensize so my phone doesnt create a bigger canvas and then scale it down again.
2. scale up the scene by factor 2. This will cut the used pixels in halve, so you have actually a smaller canvas stretched over the full screen
3. dont use clearRect to clear the entire canvas and then redraw everything. Actually removing the clearRect at your bouncing ball example will show a lot of improvement. Clearing the areas that actually change (bats and ball) and then redraw it will be enough.

On a side not I noticed that android 2 and 4 perform faster then 3, but that is based on testing with just 3 devices, so not hard stats.

I also read that using translate3d on a canvas will trigger hardware rendering if available, but I havent checked/confirmed this.

Some code that might help you:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5, user-scalable=no"/>


$(gameEl).css('-webkit-transform', 'scale3d(2, 2, 0) translate3d(0, 0, 0)');
$(gameEl).css('-webkit-transform-origin', '0 0');
```